# MySQL join query but dont show results from the first table if it's a duplicate

Tags: php, mysql

So basically I have 2 tables:

**table1**

```
id| name
1   Test
2   Something
3   More
```

**table2**

```
id| table1_id
1   1
2   1
3   1
4   2
5   2
6   3
```

Now I need the result to be like this:

```
name      | table2.id
Test        1
            2
            3
Something   4
            5
More        6
```

So basically no duplicate entries from the first table. So the exact same results as joining it but without showing the name more than once. Is this possible in MySQL or should I just filter it in PHP? I know it's possible in PHP but I am wondering if something like this is achievable in MySQL if so, I'd like to know what to look for. I was thinking something with DISTINCT and/or a left or right join.

Comment: Yes, it is possible in MySQL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, you asked if it is possible with MySQL and I answered in comments that it is. 
If your question was how can I accomplish this with only MySQL, here it is:

```
SELECT
tmp.name,
tbl2.id
FROM
    tbl2
LEFT JOIN (
SELECT
    tbl2.id AS id,
    tbl1.`name` AS name
FROM
    tbl2
INNER JOIN tbl1 ON tbl1.id = tbl2.tbl1_id
GROUP BY
    tbl2.tbl1_id
) AS tmp ON tbl2.id = tmp.id;
```

Hope it is what you wanted.

As @roberto06 suggested, this query returns `NULL` instead of duplicates, but if you don't like `NULL`s and want an empty string you can change `SELECT tmp.name` to  `SELECT IFNULL(tmp.name,'')`

Comment: Either Im doing something wrong or this is not right. I still get duplicate tbl1.names

Comment: Do you have duplicates in your table1?

Comment: Yeah nevermind. Something wrong at my end. I got it fixed. It works.

Comment: This request shows `NULL` values instead of blank ones on my test DB, I suggest you replace `SELECT tmp.name,` by `SELECT IFNULL(tmp.name,''),` at the beginning of the query ;)

Comment: @roberto06 it's a good suggestion, but it depends what the OP wants to achieve, I didn't want to assume he wants an empty string ;)

Comment: I assumed that because his example shows blank values but you could be right. Better safe than sorry, I guess.

Answer (score 1):

What about this?

```
SELECT
*, 
(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(`id`) separator '|') AS table2_ids 
FROM table2 WHERE table1_id = table1.id) AS m
FROM table1
```

In PHP, you just need to `explode('|', $mvar)`

Answer (score 1):

Found it !

```
SELECT (
    SELECT
        IF(COUNT(t2_2.table1_id) = 1, t1.name, '')
        FROM table2 t2_2
        WHERE t2_2.id <= t2.id
            AND t2_2.table1_id = t1.id
    ) AS name,
    t2.id
FROM table1 t1
    LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON t2.table1_id = t1.id
```

Results:

```
name      | .id
----------+-----
Test      |  1
          |  2
          |  3
Something |  4
          |  5
More      |  6
```

Explanation :

1. This will count the number of occurences of `table1_id` IN `t2_2` where `t2_2.id` is lower or equal than the actual `t2.id` and where `t2_2.table1_id` is equal to `t1.id`

   - So this will return `1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1` in your table example
2. Then it'll output `t1.name` if it is evaluated to `1` and an empty string if not.

I don't know if it's clear enough, and I'm pretty sure the performance could be enhanced but hey, it works.

Answer (score -1):

This is a question of presenting the query result, so I would opt for PHP, which is better at handling this than MySQL.

Comment: But if it's possible in mysql, it would (I think) be better for performance to just get it in the query.

Comment: I don't think it is easily done in SQL, that is why I suggest doing it in PHP.

Answer (score -2):

Something like this:

`select distinct t1.name, t2.id
from table1 as t1 outer right join table2 as t2 on t1.id = t2.table1_id`

Comment: This is showing me the exact same result as without distinct so its still duplicating the t1.name

Comment: OK, then it is impossible in SQL.

Answer (score -2):

You can try like...

```
select A.name,B.id from table1 A
right join table2 B on A.id=B.table1_id
```